# Spring not loading controller and no console errors

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have an existing webapp written in Struts 1.2 and i'm trying to use Spring 3-Rest to expose functionality as web services.

I've run into a basic problem that I am unable to wrap my head around

This is my web.xml stripped of all struts stuff.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <display-name>Test</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My app-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.base.rest">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/JSP/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I've got a basic controller in com.base.rest

```
package com.base.rest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class DummyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/dummy",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Dummy");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I've got hello.jsp in WebRoot/JSP folder that just prints Dummy

When deployed on tomcat 7, I get this

INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'app'

without any error on the console.

I have removed all conflicting jars from build path and just have the spring dist and commons-logging-1.1

I get a 404 when accessing server/Test/dummy

Can anyone point out what stupid mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Change your dispatcher servlet mapping to this and give it a try.

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also, in the InternalResourceViewResolver declaration the

```
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/JSP/" />
```

The value should point to the  WEB-INF/JSP location.